# Trouble connecting to Postgresql database in Vagrant guest box with Induction from host machine?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, vagrant, induction

I'm trying to connect to my PostgreSQL database which is inside of a guest machine (using Vagrant and VirtualBox).

I'm trying to connect to it with [Induction](http://inductionapp.com/), but I am getting an error saying:

```
Connection Error
Could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.1234"
```

I have Vagrant doing a port forward to port 1234 on my host machine.

My settings for the Induction connection are:

```
Adapter: postgres
Host Name: 127.0.0.1
Username: vagrant
Password: [i don't have a password for the vagrant user for postgres so leaving empty]
Port: 1234
Database: development
```

The development database was created by Rails using `rake db:create:all` and I know that it works because I see it from the Rails db console.

In my postgresql.conf file, I have set `listen_addresses` to `'*'` to listen to external machines also.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT (adding my pg_hba.conf):

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

EDIT (this is the error that shows from the Induction app when trying to connect)

```
could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.1234"
```

Answer (score 1):

check file pg_hba.conf
looks like require allow connection most easy and lesss secure set 'trust' (everyone can use your postgresql)
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: hi user647622 - i just added my pg_hba.conf configuration, i changed the local connection to trust METHOD.  but it still doesn't work.

Comment: hi @user647622 please see my edit for the error returned when trying to connect with Induction

Comment: if i correct understand you want connect from your host to database on virtual machine. if true - require change ip from 127.0.0.1 to vm's ip. and add to pg_hba string `host    all             all                              md5`

Comment: so in the pg_hba.conf should it be host all all VM ADDRESS md5?

Comment: or should it just be host all all [leave address blank] md5 i apologize for all of the questions. i'm not very familiar with postgres or VMs @user647622

Comment: host all all [leave address blank] md5

Comment: I just tried host all all [leave address blank] md5 and it doesn't work. It also breaks my ability to connect to the Postgres from my Rails App (sitting in the guest machine) which I access from my host machine's browser

Comment: amazing issue description :)

Comment: Also check what the postgresql.conf says.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that connection error when the PostgreSQL service is not running.

Check the status of the PostgreSQL service: `sudo service postgresql status`

Start the service: `sudo service postgresql status`